# ColdFusion: Getting ORA-28000: the account is locked when running cfschedule

Tags: oracle, coldfusion

I have simple cfschedule task which uses check_settings.cfm. The check_settings has the following content

```
<cftry>
<cfquery name="get_settings" datasource="#request.dsn#">
    select id, setting_value
    from tbl_appsettings
    where scope = 'A'
    and active = 1
</cfquery>
<cfcatch type="any">
    <cfmail from="admin@abc.com"
            to="user@abc.com"
            subject="Settings check"
            type="html">
            We have encountered a problem.<br />
            cfcatch.Message = #cfcatch.Message#<br />
            cfcatch.Detail = #cfcatch.Detail#<br />
            The program has been aborted.
    </cfmail>
    <cfabort>
</cfcatch>
```

The task is scheduled monthly but when it last ran it gave the error:

cfcatch.Message = Error Executing Database Query.
cfcatch.Detail = [Macromedia][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-28000: the account is locked.

Can this be caused by a expired db password in DSN settings. I do know that our web admin changes password every 3 months due some security policy. Could this be the reason?

Answer (score 4):

What is probably happening is that the account got locked because of failed logins. And yes, that would be because of an expired database password in the ColdFusion DSN. You will have to update the password to the correct one (not sure where the web admin comes in; you should contact your DBA) and then the account can be unlocked.

I would check to make sure that the scheduled task ran properly on previous occasions. It could be that it failed because the login attempt failed, and that is what caused the account to be locked.

Your DBA should also be able to change the number of failed attempts that trigger a locked account. I think this value is 10 in the current version of Oracle.

On a side note, it's possible that you don't have an expired password, but the account was locked because someone else was trying to log in with an incorrect password.

Comment: Thanks for the reply David. Only thing that is causing doubt in my mind is that if the DSN password is incorrect then it CF should throw "Error Executing Database Query. - Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up." So I am assuming that may be the admin has changed the DB password without informing the users and when multiple users tried the old password the account got locked. I am still investigating

Comment: I don't think CF is even getting to the point at which it would check the stored DSN password - my guess is that Oracle is returning the "account locked" error before password is even checked. I'd rather not try to lock myself out of my account to check that theory though :)